# Django urlsafe_base64_decode returns None

Tags: django

So I'm making an email verification system but urlsafe_base64_decode is returning None instead of the pk.

```
def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():

        user = form.save(commit=False)

        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']

        subject = 'Activá tu mail'
        current_site = get_current_site(request)
        encoded_uid = urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode()
        message = render_to_string('firstpage/acc_active_email.html', {
            'user': user,
            'domain': current_site.domain,
            'uid': encoded_uid,
            'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
        to_email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        from_email = 'backend_email@gmail.com'
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [to_email])

        user.set_password(password)

        user.save()
        user_profile=UserProfile.objects.create(user=user)
        #returns user objects if credentials are correct
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:

            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/')

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Then the users clicks on a link and this is redirected to this function

```
def activate(request, uidb64=None, token=None):
    uid = urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64).decode()
    user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        # return redirect('home')
        return HttpResponse('Thank you for your email confirmation. Now you can login your account.')
    else:
        print(user)
        print(uid)
        print(account_activation_token.check_token(user, token))
        return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

uidb64 returns the same as urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode() but urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64).decode() returns None.

I'm using Django 2.1 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `force_text` to return a str object representing arbitrary object and keep the lazy objects, use this - `force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))`
For more reference you can visit the documentation

-https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.encoding.force_text

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is very late. But for anyone like me that stumbles upon this and has the exact same problem.
Django 3 >>
The problem is on this line

```
'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
```

And the reason is because the user given here is a form instead of a proper user instance. 
Therefore, for solution:

```
user_instance = request.user # if the user is logged in or
user_instance = get_user_model() # if you're using default user model or
user_instance = YourUserModel # if you are using a custom user model
```

Then:

```
'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user_instance),
```